# How can I define a function with a foor loop inside and with a condfitional if statement inside the for loop?

Tags: r

I am trying to define a function with a for loop and inside a conditional in R studio. For that, I started with a simple case which is in the following code. However, it is not working.

```
ma<-rep(0,20)

l<-function(x){for (i in 1:20){
  if (i%%2 ==1) {ma[i]=i+x}
  
  else {ma[i]=0}} 
}
```

For the original case I need the above structure. However I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Question:

Can someone explain me how to create a function with these conditions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change the function to

```
l <- function(x, ma) {
         for(i in seq_along(ma)) {
             if(i %% 2 == 1) {
                 ma[i] <- i + x
              } else {
                 ma[i] <- 0
        }
        }
    return(ma)
   }
```

-testing

```
ma <- rep(0, 20)
l(5, ma)
#[1]  6  0  8  0 10  0 12  0 14  0 16  0 18  0 20  0 22  0 24  0
```

---

These are vectorized operators, so a `for` loop is not really required here

```
ifelse(seq_along(ma) %% 2 == 1, seq_along(ma) + 5, 0)
#[1]  6  0  8  0 10  0 12  0 14  0 16  0 18  0 20  0 22  0 24  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `ma` is not an argument passed to function `l`, you can try `<<-` rather than `<-` if `ma` is from the parent environment of `l`

```
l <- function(x) {
  for (i in 1:20) {
    if (i %% 2 == 1) {
      ma[i] <<- i + x
    }
    else {
      ma[i] <<- 0
    }
  }
}
```

then you will see

```
> l(5)
> ma
 [1]  6  0  8  0 10  0 12  0 14  0 16  0 18  0 20  0 22  0 24  0
```

---

## Note

However, `<<-` might be one workaround but not recommended. A better solution than this can be found from [akrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67462713/12158757).